# Утечка памяти в функции с++

Tags: c++

Есть такое задание :

> Реализуйте функцию getline, которая считывает поток ввода посимвольно, пока не достигнет конца потока или не встретит символ переноса строки ('\n'), и возвращает C-style строку с прочитанными символами.
>
> Обратите внимание, что так как размер ввода заранее неизвестен, то вам нужно будет перевыделять память в процессе чтения, если в потоке ввода оказалось больше символов, чем вы ожидали.
>
> Память, возвращенная из функции будет освобождена оператором delete[]. Символ переноса строки ('\n') добавлять в строку не нужно, но не забудьте, что в конце C-style строки должен быть завершающий нулевой символ.
>
> Требования к реализации: при выполнении данного задания вы можете определять любые вспомогательные функции, если они вам нужны. Определять функцию main не нужно.

Я написал такую функцию:

```
int g = 0;
int i = 0;
char c;
int k = 1;
char * m = new char[k];
char * str = 0;

while (((c = std::cin.get()) != '\n') && (!std::cin.eof())) {

    g = 0;
    i = 0;

    str = new char[k];

    while ((m[i]) && (m[i] != '\0')) {
        str[i] = m[i];
        i += 1;
    }

    delete [] m;
    m = 0;
    str[i] = c;
    m = new char[k];

    while (str[g]) {
        m[g] = str[g];
        g++;
    }
    delete [] str;
    str = 0;
    k += 1;
}   

m[i+1] = '\0';

return m;
```

При небольшом количестве символов все работает хорошо. Но когда символов больше 20, то код крашится. Я догадываюсь, что проблема в утечке памяти, но найти ошибку не могу. Как исправить функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Признаться честно, сложно понять, что у вас происходит в коде. Но падает программа из-за попытки чтения за пределами строки.

> ```
> while ((m[i]) && (m[i] != '\0')) ...
> ```

Это условие цикла какое-то очень странное. Вы хотите найти ноль, который вы туда не записываете (точнее пытаетесь записать, но после этого цикла).

Думаю, стоит ознакомиться, с моим адаптированным примерчиком. Копирование тут реализовано вызовом библиотечной функции [std::copy](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
char* get_full_line(std::istream& f = std::cin)
{
    size_t capacity = 16;  // начальный объем массива
    char* str = new char[capacity];
    size_t length = 0;

    int ch;
    while ((ch = f.get()) != '\n' && !f.eof()) {
        if (length >= capacity) {
            // место в строке закончилось, перевыделение памяти
            char* p = new char[capacity *= 4];  // коэфициент прироста
            std::copy(str, str + length, p);
            delete[] str;
            str = p;
        }
        str[length++] = ch;
    }
    str[length] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, переписал код и все получилось.